# vb.net JSON Is Nothing in nested

Tags: json, vb.net

Snippet From JSON

```
 "stats": [
    {
      "stat": 32,
      "amount": 651,
      "reforgedAmount": -434
    },
    {
      "stat": 5,
      "amount": 2001
    },
    {
      "stat": 36,
      "amount": 1544
    },
    {
      "stat": 7,
      "amount": 3362
    },
    {
      "stat": 49,
      "amount": 434,
      "reforged": true
    }
  ],
  "armor": 2244
},
```

my current code

```
stat0lbl.Text = If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString()) + Environment.NewLine + If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(1)("stat").ToString()) + Environment.NewLine + If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(2)("stat").ToString()) + Environment.NewLine + If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(3)("stat").ToString()) + Environment.NewLine + If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(4)("stat").ToString()) + Environment.NewLine + If(jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(5) Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(5)("stat").ToString())
```

this code works perfectly until it comes to stat 5 in the array, im not sure how to handle the Is Nothing in an array

Comment: what your code is trying to do?

Comment: output each stat on a new line in a label i know how to display the data but im not sure how to use the is nothing inside the nested

Answer (score 0):

I think pushing to do this logic in single line doesn't bring any advantage but far less readable code (and redundant checking `jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Nothing`). I'd suggest to do it in standard `If` block (if possible) :

```
If jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text) Is Not Nothing Then
    Dim newStat = _
        jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() & Environment.NewLine & _
        jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(1)("stat").ToString() & Environment.NewLine & _
        jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(2)("stat").ToString() & Environment.NewLine & _
        jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(3)("stat").ToString() & Environment.NewLine & _
        jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(4)("stat").ToString() & Environment.NewLine

    If jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats").Count() > 5 Then
        newStat &= jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(5)("stat").ToString()
    End If

    stat0lbl.Text = newStat
End If
```

I assume that the main confusion is on how to check if `stat` at index 5 exists.  One possible way, as demonstrated above is, using `.Count()` to check how many data (`stat`) in collection (`stats`). If `.Count()` return more than 5, means there is data at index 5.

Comment: when i use the count function i seem to be getting an exception `{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

Comment: it is my (itemtypelbl.Text) that is causing the issue, is it possible to define a value using the text from itemtypelbl and use it in the string?

Comment: yes, it is possible. if the issue was null reference as in your 1st comment, first step is to find out which variable is null. [for reference on how to avoid NullReferenceException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i already know itemtypelbl.Text was causing the null to return what im not sure how to do is `Dim stat0 As String stat0 = stat0lbl.text` then use that in a way like `If jResults("items")(stat0)("stats").Count() > 5 Then .....` i have tried it this way and it still throws the exception without physically typing it like this `If jResults("items")("head")("stats").Count() > 5 Then ...` when i format it like that it seems to work fine but i dont want to type it for every item which is why i was using `itemtypelbl.text` as this is set by the parent form for each item

Comment: Which one was null, Text property of `stat0lbl` or `stat0lbl` it self? how about adding null checking? if it is null don't proceed with reading `jResults`

Comment: im not sure i understand when i use the `jResults("items")("head")("stats")(0)("stat")` on its own WITHOUT count it works fine so nothing is null i just cant use .count like `If jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats").Count() > 5 Then` so when i ad count its changing how it is being read some how and im unable to determine what and unable to see a null you refer to

Comment: that (the 1st snippet) was WITHOUT count and WITHOUT itemtypelbl.Text. so there are 2 suspects, you need to find out which one causing the problem. Try this way and see if exception still thrown : `jResults("items")("head")("stats").Count() > 5`

Comment: i think we may be getting confused here, in an earlier post i have said `If jResults("items")("head")("stats").Count() > 5 Then` -- Works Fine But Not Ideal | `mylbl.text = jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats")(0)("stat")` - Works Fine | But `If jResults("items")(itemtypelbl.Text)("stats").Count() > 5 Then` Throws An Exception so it has somthing to do with the either .count or using the label text and count together :)